# Why are points neutral in magnetic fields?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I’m going through a couple of T/F statements in class.

One I’m stumped with,

“If a point in the magnetic field is neutral, it’s magnetic field vector components are all 0”

At first sight it looks true - because the point is neutral. But I don’t know if I’m missing something?

Comment: I have no idea what it means for "a point in the magnetic field" to be "neutral."  Do you have a resource which uses this language, or is this just something your instructor has said?

Comment: I’m certain it means a point in space where the magnetic field is zero - don’t know if that’s the correct term.

Comment: Well, in that case it seems to be a relatively straightforward question, do you have any specific conceptual issue with it?

Comment: A number of mentions of neutral point on this website including [Position of neutral points](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/365220/position-of-neutral-points).  A *neutral point* is  a position at which the magnetic field is zero.

Comment: @Farcher Oh, interesting. When I was doing neutron polarimetry, where a nonzero magnetic field is required for adiabatic spin transport, we referred to such points as “zeros in the magnetic field” or “field zeros.”

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a vocabulary issue: we use “neutral” to refer to the absence of *electric charge*, which is mostly independent of the presence or absence of a magnetic field. You can have a zero magnetic field or a nonzero magnetic field at the location of a particle whose electric charge is positive, negative, or zero.

The construction “a point is neutral” is not one I’ve encountered before; it doesn’t quite scan correctly for me. It could be the author meant something different. Tread carefully.